# Change of variable in Fourier series

Tags: fourier-series

[image]

I am not finding any document online discussing how changing the variable affects the Fourier series. Any thought on the rule ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

The series for $f(2x)$ is identical to the new series, so they must be the same over some interval.

To resolve this seemingly paradoxical result, ask yourself:

> What's the period of the original series? What can you say
>   about the period of the new series?

Comment: The new one has half the original period ?